# Difference between "bootable flag" and /boot mount point

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

In partition table, we can give `/boot` as mount point. But we can, too, toggle `bootable flag`. What's difference between those two?

Answer (score 3):

As for boot flag, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag). It is usually not needed for Ubuntu installation.

Boot mount point is the partition you mount your /boot to, if you use a separate /boot partition. If you do not have a separate /boot partition, /boot is just a directory under /. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) for more about partitions and mount points used in Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score -1):

The `/boot` mount point specifies the location to install the bootloader (GRUB, Syslinux), to be used by legacy BIOS-based systems in order to boot when the actual boot device contains a GUID Partition Table (GPT).

A boot flag, on the other hand, is a 1-byte value in a non-extended partition record, within a master boot record. Its primary function is to indicate to a MS-DOS/MS Windows-type boot loader which partition to boot.

---

If you have an MBR (Master Boot Record) type partition table, all you need to do is to set a boot flag on the root filesystem `/`. However, if you have a GPT partition table, you need to create a separate BIOS boot partition and install GRUB to it.

Comment: So, is it okay to create one partition with `/boot` as mount point and `bootable flag` is activated?

Comment: Usually better for most desktops not to even have a /boot partition. Server type installs or LVM encrypted installs may need a /boot partition. Grub boot loader does not use boot flag, but a few BIOS want to see a boot flag on a primary partition which is only a Windows requirement, but also used by syslinux on live installer. so we still suggest a boot flag on a primary partition, just in case you have one of those few BIOS (mostly Intel motherboards).

Comment: I have added the information to the answer.

Comment: BIOS boot partition is not mounted as /boot; see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#BIOS-Boot_or_EFI_partition_.28required_on_GPT_disks.29).