# no idication of boot partition

Tags: partitioning

[image]

Doe anybody know where is boot  placed ?

Comment: The `lsblk` command would give information about block devices' mount points. Bear in mind that `/boot` does not *have* to be a separate partition.

Comment: I saw on some  comments that usually * is placed besides partition in BOOT. I do not find it here . strange I believe

Comment: You likely heard about the [boot flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag) - AFAIK it's not required for Linux systems (at least, not those that use `grub` as the boot loader). See for example [Difference between “bootable flag” and /boot mount point](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571785/difference-between-bootable-flag-and-boot-mount-point)

Comment: With BIOS/MBR, part of grub is in MBR or very first sector of hard drive. And part of grub (core.img) is in sectors just after MBR but before first partition. And then parts of grub are in /boot folder whether in / (root) or a separate partition. And some grub configuration files are in /etc, several locations.